# LINQ to Entities for subtracting 2 dates

Tags: entity-framework, datetime, linq-to-entities

I am trying to determine the number of days between 2 dates using LINQ with Entity Framework. It is telling me that it does not recognize Subtract on the System.TimeSpan class

Here is my where portion of the LINQ query.

```
where ((DateTime.Now.Subtract(vid.CreatedDate).TotalDays < maxAgeInDays))
```

Here is the error I receive in the VS.NET debugger

> {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to get the number of days between 2 DateTimes in the entity framework?

thanks
Michael

Comment: I also tried to avoid timespan by changing the formula a bit to the following - which still doesn't work

where (vid.CreatedDate.AddDays(maxAgeInDays) >= DateTime.Now)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work

I defined a datetime variable that represents the oldest date

```
DateTime oldestDate = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(maxAgeInDays, 0, 0, 0, 0));
...
```

then I modified the where portion of the LINQ query

```
where (vid.CreatedDate >= oldestDate )
```

worked like a charm - thanks Micah for getting me to think about the expression tree

Comment: You should have flagged @Micah as answer and either add a comment to his response or update your question with the final answer.

Comment: Clever, clever clever. Simple and straight forward. I am still wondering why it did not come to me in the first place. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 103):

The accepted answer is better in this case, but for reference you can use the [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412643.aspx) class to perform operations on dates, among other things.

```
where (vid.CreatedDate >= EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -maxAgeInDay))
```

Comment: Note that this is only supported in Entity Framework v4.  This won't work for Entity Framework v1.

Comment: Thanks for sharing EntityFunctions class. Very helpful

Comment: EntityFunctions is deprecated.  DbFunctions is the new class.

Comment: Thanks and for me EntityFunctions.DiffDays by @Ladislav Mrnka did the job.

Comment: Anyone used `DbFunctions` with unit tests?  I have had no luck with that.

Comment: As other have noted, EntityFunctions is deprecated. Here's a full example for copy/paste purposes:
`System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -maxAgeInDay)`

Comment: `DbFunctions` no longer appears to be the way to use this anymore either. It's now under `EF.Functions` in EFCore 3

Answer (score 23):

You can also use `System.Data.Objects.EntityFucntions`:

```
currentDate = DateTime.Now;

...
where  EntityFunctions.DiffDays(currentDate, vid.CreatedDate) < maxAgeIdDays
```

All functions from `EntityFunctions` are only for Linq-to-entities and are mapped to SQL functions.

Comment: @Morten: That was type, they work only with Linq-to-entities.

Comment: Many SQL Server specific functions are available through the `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions` class. Of course, the data store has to be a SQL Server for this to work. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx

Comment: Also worth noting once you upgrade to EF 6+ the System.Data.Objects.EntityFucntions becomes obsolete, instead use: System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions

Comment: this function is deprecate use DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(o.DateReceived, o.DateOrder) istead

Answer (score 12):

You run into these kind of isses because the predicate needs to be translated to an expression tree. And translation process doesn't recognize the DateTime.Now.Subtract method.

Comment: is there anyway to do what I am trying to do so that i can be translated into an expression tree?

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that by design, LINQ to Entities needs to translate the whole query to SQL statements. That's where it cannot recognize Subtract method. It will occur whenever you try to use a C#/VB method inside a query. In these cases you have to figure out a way to bring out that part from the query.
This post explains a bit more:
http://mosesofegypt.net/post/LINQ-to-Entities-what-is-not-supported.aspx

Comment: This answer is correct, but it's definitely not the answer I wanted. LINQ to SQL supported calling outside methods as much as you liked, so this trade-off is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

You may define new property in your model:

```
    public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate{ get; set; }
    public TimeSpan CalculateTime{
        get
        {
            return EndDate.Subtract(StartDate);
        }
    }
```

Now, you may use something like that:

```
var query = from temp in db.Table
select new MyModel {
    Id = temp.Id,
    Variable1 = temp.Variable1,
    ...
    EndDate = temp.EndDate,
    StartDate = temp.StartDate
}
```

When you have look at result, you may use return such as:

```
return query
```

Now, in query, we have CalculateTime (subtract between EndDate and Startdate).

Comment: that works only when you have access to the model's source code.