# How do I convert the following functions/expressions from SQL to LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

```
Dateadd(minute, TS.duration, TS.datesched)
```

WHERE...

```
TS.Duration = int.
TS.datesched = datetime.

RTRIM(ISNULL(TC.CityLocation, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(TC.StateLocation, '')
```

WHERE...

```
TC.CityLocation = varchar(50)
TC.StateLocation = varchar(10)

CASE
WHEN country = market 
OR country = 'USA' THEN market 
ELSE country + ' | ' + market 
END AS BroadcastMarket
```

WHERE...

```
Country = varchar(100)
Market = varchar(100)

CASE 
WHEN country = 'USA' THEN 0 
ELSE 1 
END AS CountrySort
```

WHERE...

```
Country = varchar(100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to try an take a stab at this. Basically what your looking for is a projection.

`TcCollection` is your data set.

```
var result = (from i in TcCollection
              select new 
              {
                  Date = EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(i.datesched, i.duration),
                  Location = (i.CityLocation ?? "") + " " + (i.StateLocation ?? ""),
                  BroadcastMarket = 
                      (i.market == i.country || i.country == "USA") ? 
                      i.market : 
                      i.country + " | " + i.market,
                  CountrySort = (i.country == "USA") ? 0 : 1
              });
```

Comment: Thanks to Sandy who provided the date part I missed initially.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Entity Functions for date operations like AddDays,AddMinutes in LINQ. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570858/linq-to-entities-for-subtracting-2-dates) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.addminutes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A case in the Select will be done in the projection of the LINQ.  You could have a multiline anonymous method so that you could have if/else statements instead, but here I show just using a ternary operator.

```
CASE 
WHEN country = 'USA' THEN 0 
ELSE 1 
END AS CountrySort
```

Becomes:

```
.Select(c=> new { countrySort = (c.country == "USA" ? 0 : 1)});
```