# My ForEach loop with a LINQ expression cannot be translated?

Tags: c#, foreach, entity-framework-core

I need to go through all my chemicals and send out a warning to users if the expiration date is either 2 days away or 15 days away.
I have it set like that so the warning is sent out twice.  Once 2 weeks before it expires, and once 2 days before it expires.

So I have this loop:

```
foreach (var chemical in _context.Chemical.Where(c => (c.DateOfExpiration - DateTime.Now).TotalDays == 15 || (c.DateOfExpiration - DateTime.Now).TotalDays == 2))
{
    // send out notices
    var base = _context.Base.Find(chemical.BaseId);
    var catalyst = _context.Catalyst.Find(chemical.CatalystId);

    _warningService.SendSafetyWarning(chemical, base, catalyst.Name);
}
```

But whenever I run it, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Chemical>
.Where(p => (p.DateOfExpiration - DateTime.Now).TotalDays == 15 || (p.DateOfExpiration - DateTime.Now).TotalDays == 2)'
could not be translated.
```

I'm not sure why it's giving me this error when I run it.

Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: [EntityFunctions.DiffDays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5974722/15393) will probably resolve your issue.

Comment: I agree with @rb.  With your code as it stands, basically each time around the for loop, DateTime.Now would have changed, which means the query will change, which is obviously not good.

Comment: I'd recommend creating the two dates you want to check for like `var fifteenDays = DateTime.Today.AddDays(15);` then you'd need to compare the truncated date of `DateOfExpiration` to them.  Based on the error I think you're using an older EF which would require `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.DateOfExpiration)` unless you only store the date in that column.

Comment: @RB. You mean put something like this in my `foreach` loop?  `where  EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, c.DateOfExpiration) == 2 || EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, c.DateOfExpiration) == 15`

Comment: @Rb Is `EntityFunctions` deprecated?  The question you linked to contains comments that it is deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DateTime.TotalDays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totaldays?view=net-5.0) returns a double.

You might have more luck changing your code to:

```
foreach (var chemical in _context.Chemical.Where(c => ((int)(c.DateOfExpiration - DateTime.Now).TotalDays == 15) || ((int)(c.DateOfExpiration - DateTime.Now).TotalDays == 2)))
{
    // send out notices
    var base = _context.Base.Find(chemical.BaseId);
    var catalyst = _context.Catalyst.Find(chemical.CatalystId);

    _warningService.SendSafetyWarning(chemical, base, catalyst.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this problem.

I'll first explain why it is throwing an error. EF is converting your code to an SQL `Expression`. When working with `Expression` you cannot parse in any C# code and expect it to work. EF needs to be able to translate it to SQL. That is why you are getting the exception saying that it can't translate your code.

When working directly in the `Where` clause on the `DbSet` or the `DbContext` you are actualy talking to the `Where` method for an `IQueryable`. Which has a parameter of `Expression<Func<bool, T>>` where `T` is your `DbSet<T>` type.

You either need to simplify your query so it can be translated to SQL. Or you can convert your `IQueryable` to an `IEnumerable`.

When you want to run your query on the SQL server, you need to use the first approach. But when you can run your query on the client you can use the second approach.

The first approached as mentioned by vivek nuna is using `EntityFunctions`. It might not be enough for your use case, because it has limited functionality.

The statement made that `DateTime.Now` is different on each iteratoion is not true. Because the query is converted once, it isn't running the query on every iteration. It simply doesn't know how to translate your query to SQL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.entityfunctions?view=netframework-4.8

The second approach means adding `AsEnumerable` after your `DbSet`. This will query all your data from your SQL server, and evaluate in C#. This is usually not recommended if you have a large data set. Example:

```cs
var chemicals = _context.Chemical.AsEnumerable(); // this will get the complete collection

chemicals.Where(i => i.Value == true); // everything will work now
```

---

And answer to a "better" approach. It's a bit cleaner code:

If you have navigation properties for your `Base` and `Catalyst` you can also include this in your query.

Note that you can still query server side before pulling everything client side using a `Where` on the `_context.Chemical` and then including and calling `AsEnumerable`.

```cs
var chemicals = _context.Chemical.Include(i => i.Base).Include(i => i.Catalyst).AsEnumerable();

foreach (var chemical in chemicals.Where(i => true)) // set correct where clause
{
    _warningService.SendSafetyWarning(chemical, chemical.Base, chemical.Catalyst);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable before and then pass it to your expression. Like `DateOfExpiration == nextFifteenDays` …..

```
var nextFifteenDays = DateTime.Now.Adddays(15);


var nextTwoDays = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
```

Or you can use `EntityFunctions.Diffdays`

Reason for the error is well explained by @neil that DateTime.Now will keep on changing, so can’t be used.

Comment: So it's the `DateTime.Now` in my `where` statement that is making it error? thanks!

Comment: Yes @neil also added the reason for your error

Comment: `TotalDays` is your error.

Comment: @viveknuna I took the `DateTime.Now` out of the expression.  I then added the variable as you did and put that variable inside my expression, but I still get the same error

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv what is wrong with my TotalDays?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell my bad, actually I’m not in front of PC . So couldn’t try tum run. better created two variables then, one for fifteen days and one for two days and then use in your query. It will work

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell, `TotalDays` is not translatable to the SQL Use `EntityFunctions.Diffdays`

Comment: Your answer it not true, only the `EntityFunctions` part is correct. Consider updating it